# addChildWindow equivalent for Windows platform

Tags: windows, cocoa, nswindow

On Cocoa, to lock a child window to its parent window, one can use addChildWindow:ordered: from the Cocoa library.

I am looking for a similar method on Windows for cross-platform developping.

Do you know of any equivalent method on Windows ?

Comment: What do you looking for exactly?

Comment: To lock window B to window A.
If I move window A, it will also move window B

Answer (score 0):

Child ('WS_CHILD' namely) windows are **always** moved with parent, they have not need to be locked.

But if you mean floating ('WS_POPUP' for example) windows - there is no way to "lock" them in WinAPI. You need to process WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, for example, and reposition your floating windows manually.